# Wix get user from a running Windows Service

Tags: .net, windows, installation, wix, wix3.5

I'd like to know if there is any built-in functionality to obtain the User that is running a Windows Service using Wix 3.5. I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058681/check-if-service-is-running-in-wix) where it's stated that there is nothing built into Wix to check for a Service Status. I think that if this is not possible, then  getting the User that runs the service is far more impossible. 
Using a Custom Action is a last resort.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a registry search for HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ServiceName|ObjectName but that assumes nothing updated the registry value without restarting the service. (Potential disconnect).

Programatically (custom action) you can interact with the SCM API (win32) or WMI (win32_service class StartName attribute) to get more detailed information.

I agree with avoiding CA's but if the only purpose of the CA is to gather data and not change machine state, it can be done very robustly with little downside.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've found really useful the registry branch you mentioned. Could you please explain this part : "but that assumes nothing updated the registry value without restarting the service.". Also i realized that i am obtaining the value in the "DOMAIN\USERNAME" format from the registry. I only need the USERNAME part so i need to "substring" the value. I've seen is not possible to do this in Wix. So anyway, i'll need a custom action to format the RegitryValue.

Comment: If I set the user to bob and start the service, the service is running as bob.  If I then set it to ed it is still running as bob until I stop and start the service again.   For the second part, there is no string splt capabiltiy in Windows Installer and therefore none in WiX.  You would have to write a custom action that read the one property, parsed it and then wrote it to another property.

Comment: Thanks, the answer is very useful. In the end I will have to build a CA anyway.